# Web audio API ChannelMergerNode not working as expected on Safari

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I've created a simple jsfiddle using ChannelMergerNode, to play oscillator on the right speaker.
It works as expected on Chrome, but on Safari the sound plays to both speakers (right and left).

```
var audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new audioContext();
var merger = context.createChannelMerger();
merger.connect(context.destination);
var osc = context.createOscillator();
osc.connect(merger, 0, 1);
osc.start();
osc.stop(10.0);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RivkaB/tcnofjy1/16/

Any idea how solve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you simply trying to play one sound on the right speaker or do you need the `ChannelMergerNode` for more than that purpose?

Comment: My audio needs are not so simple. I need the ability to play on right/left ear only, both, or play one sound on the right and the other on the left at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The `ChannelMergerNode` interface is used to *merge* channels that have been split-up by a `ChannelSplitterNode` into a single channel. The panning effect that you get might be a side effect of the Chrome implementation of that node, although I'm not sure.

If you wan't to create a stereo panning effect then create a [`StereoPannerNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode) which allows you to control the output on the left and right side.

The `StereoPannerNode` has a `pan` property. This property has a `value` property which can be a number ranging from `-1` (left) to `1` (right), with `0` being the center.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const stereoPannerNode = audioContext.createStereoPanner();
const oscillatorNode = audioContext.createOscillator();
  
oscillatorNode.connect(stereoPannerNode);
stereoPannerNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (button.value === 'play') {
      oscillatorNode.start();
    } else if (button.value === 'left') {
      stereoPannerNode.pan.value = -1;
    } else if (button.value === 'right') {
      stereoPannerNode.pan.value = 1;
    } else {
      stereoPannerNode.pan.value = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button value="play">Play</button>
<button value="left">Only left</button>
<button value="right">Only right</button>
<button value="both">Both</button>
```

Comment: @rivka is this of any help?

Comment: StereoPannerNode is not supported on iOS Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I think Safari hasn't updated its `ChannelMergerNode` to follow the spec.  It's been a while, but I think what's happening is that since you only connect one input, the output contains just the one channel, basically ignoring the unconnected input 0.

If you want this to work with Safari, you need to connect something to input 0.  This could be your oscillator connected to a zero-gain node.  Or maybe a looping `AudioBufferSourceNode` with a buffer of all zeros.

But I'm not 100% sure this will work either.  If this doesn't work, use `AudioBufferSourceNode` with a very very tiny value, like 1e-20.